# Hibernate session managment

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate+jsp+postgres database

```
void TestMethod(){
HibernateSessionManager hs=new HibernateSessionManager();
Session ses=hs.preHandle();         
 //  Here  is my code that uses session
    ------
    ------
hs.afterCompletion(ses);
}
```

Here is code for `preHandle` and `afterCompletion`

```
public Session preHandle() {

           SessionFactory sessionfactory =HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
       Session sess = sessionfactory.openSession();
     return sess;
}

public void afterCompletion(Session sess){

       if(sess!=null){  
              sess.flush();
        sess.close();
        sess=null;
      }
}
```

Is this fine that I am using the `preHandle()`  and `afterCompletion()` method for opening and closing session resp. Will it cause any problem in my code?

And also ,
 Is there a limit to the number of sessions that HibernateSessionManager will create and so refuse to create new Session objects?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you read the [reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/pdf/hibernate_reference.pdf) chapter 12.

You need to handle transactions. There are frameworks like [spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html) that help a lot with that. If you have a simple webapp and you don't want to use spring you can handle your hibernate session and transactions in a separate servlet filter.